CSS after before property not working with svg?
I can’t figure out why the pseudo-element in Input with svg doesn’t work.


.section #location{
    position: relative;
}
.section #location::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('#{$svgPath}pin.svg') ;
    width: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;  /* Установка позиции */
    left: 10px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="United State">
  <button type="button" class="search-button"></button>
</div>



What am I doing wrong?

You can't use pseudo-elements on a <input> as it is not a 'container' element.

Stack Overflow is an [English-only site]. Please try your best to [edit] your question to rewrite it in English.

Related: Can I use a :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field?

You can not use pseudo-elements on an <input> as it is not a 'container' element (ie: it is self-closing and has no children). In this case you could put the pseudo-element on the input's parent to get the same effect.


.section #location{
    position: relative;
}
.section::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="United State">
  <button type="button" class="search-button"></button>
</div>



